# Window visible on all spaces (including other fullscreen apps)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm trying to make a window (NSWindow) visible on all the spaces including other full screen app windows. I've been trying to set a higher window level as well as playing with expose and spaces settings in the inspector. I found some solutions here, but they do not work. At least on El Capitan.

Here is a sample code to test:

```
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask, backing: .Buffered, `defer`: true)
window.backgroundColor = NSColor.greenColor()
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.FloatingWindowLevelKey))
window.collectionBehavior = [.CanJoinAllSpaces, .Transient]
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

Now it displays the window on all the desktop spaces but it does not display it over the full screen windows of other apps.

Comment: have you fix this issue? i´m facing this right now and i´d appreciate some help. thx

Comment: @VaroX have you found a work around ,a good example of this is the macos loom app they always have a button on top of all apps .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want a window to be visible on top of other fullscreen windows (in spaces), you should make an agent (accessory) application.
You can do it by setting `LSUIElement` key in the application’s `Info.plist` to `1 (YES)`

If you still need a regular application you can do following:

1. Create a separate agent (helper) application inside your main application bundle which will show your window. (There are plenty of good examples on how you can create such application)
2. Play with `NSApplicationActivationPolicy`. You can try to change application's activation policy during a runtime. 
   Swift 3:

   - `NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)` switch to agent(accessory)
   - `NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)` switch to ordinary application

Keep in mind that `.accessory` policy hides the icon from Dock and you still need the code you have already:

`window.collectionBehavior = .canJoinAllSpaces
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.floatingWindow))`

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track in a way, you need to set your window object's level to one level above the Shield Window's to be in the the forefront:

```
        window.level = Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel()) + 1
```

Do note that this technique is not really recommended as some problems might arise from the interaction between full-screen graphics (OpenGL full-screen drawing contexts is an example) and the graphics hardware; but it's your best bet if you want to ensure overlay on top of all other applications.